# Parsing large .txt with user defined inputs - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

Morning guys!

This code that I wrote work for .txt file follow a pattern of having a start/completed time. When I tried seeing if it will work for different .txt files that didn't follow that pattern... It broke (obviously). The output of when it worked is below.

```
import pprint  # Fancy pretty print for python
import re  # regular expressions
 
count = 0
d = {}  # d is an empty dictionary
 
file = open(r"C:\Users\cqt7wny\Desktop\test.txt", "r")  # Open file for reading, it returns the contents of file as array (its a generator)
 
for line in file:  # Read line by line
  if '==' in line or "**" in line or not line.strip() or 'countriesshipped by day' in line:  # If line is long string of =, its a record separator, skip it
      continue
 
  if 'STARTED' in line:  # This line contains start time
      program_name, _ = line.split("STARTED")  # The pattern is <program name><space>STARTED<WHATEVER>
      start_time = line.split(' ')[-1].strip()  # Slplit line wit a space and take last component
      d[count] = ({'start_time': start_time})  # Initialize the nth record, starts with 0 as 'count' is set to 0
 
      continue
 
  if 'COMPLETED' in line:  # End time
      end_time = line.split(' ')[-1].strip()
      d[count].update({'end_time': end_time})  # Get end time
      count += 1
      continue
 
  # For every other line with = in it,  split with = to make it key/value
 
  try:
      x, y = re.split(r'\=|\:', line)
  except:
      x, y = ("", "")
      print (line)
 
  x = x.strip()  # Remove leading and trailing spaces on key
  y = y.strip()  # Remove leading and trailing spaces on value
 
  d[count].update({x: y})  # Put the key value pair into d[count]
 
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(d)
```

Output

```
{   0: {   'ADDR FOUND': '3169',
          'ADDR NOT FND': '0',
          'CALLS': '82',
          'ELIG   SYS': '3762',
          'INELIG SYS': '7',
          'Program Name': 'program1',
          'REC READ': '265',
          'REC WRITTEN': '265',
          'SHPR FOUND': '69',
          'SHPR NOT FND': '3',
          'end_time': '2017-06-07-14.35.56.067879',
          'start_time': '2017-06-07-14.31.34.827086'},
   1: {   'ADDR FOUND': '31369',
          'ADDR NOT FND': '10',
          'CALLS': '32',
          'ELIG   SYS': '762',
          'INELIG SYS': '471',
          'Program Name': 'program1',
          'REC READ': '165',
          'REC WRITTEN': '235',
          'SHPR FOUND': '649',
          'SHPR NOT FND': '23',
          'end_time': '2017-06-07-14.35.56.067879',
          'start_time': '2017-06-07-14.31.34.827086'},
   2: {   'ADDR FOUND': '3169',
          'ADDR NOT FND': '0',
          'CALLS': '82',
          'ELIG   SYS': '3762',
          'INELIG SYS': '7',
          'Program Name': 'program1',
          'REC READ': '265',
          'REC WRITTEN': '265',
          'SHPR FOUND': '69',
          'SHPR NOT FND': '3',
          'end_time': '2017-06-07-14.35.56.067879',
          'start_time': '2017-06-07-14.31.34.827086'},
   3: {   'ADDR FOUND': '31369',
          'ADDR NOT FND': '10',
          'CALLS': '32',
          'ELIG   SYS': '762',
          'INELIG SYS': '471',
          'Program Name': 'program1',
          'REC READ': '165',
          'REC WRITTEN': '235',
          'SHPR FOUND': '649',
          'SHPR NOT FND': '23',
          'end_time': '2017-06-07-14.35.56.067879',
          'start_time': '2017-06-07-14.31.34.827086'},
```

What I want to Accomplish:
My goal is now make a parser program that is able to scan through any .txt files regardless of the format and retrieve specific user defined information.

My plan/Idea?

In order for this program to work for any text files, the user will need to know every detail of the information they want the program to scan through. In other words user tells the program what it needs to search for... the program does not make any assumptions.

I want the user who is running the program to 1. Input the file name, 2. Input the program name(used as a beginning search) 3. input the delimiter (for key value pairs in file) 4. The keys for which user need values(program will run through lines seeing if the keys match a line then take the value on the right). 
 
So the procedure involves few steps.

1. GET 
   a. filename
   b. program name
   c. delimiter 
   d.list of keys from user
2. Open the file & read it
   3.Loop through each line looking for key - value pair
3. split it with separator
4. print keys and values

My current code:

```
file_name = input("File name : ")
program_name = input("Program name : ")
delimiter = input("Delimiter : ")
 
fields = input("Fields : ")
field_list = fields.split(",")
 
d = []  # d is an empty array
 
file = open(file_name, "r")  # Open file for reading, it returns the contents of file as array (its a generator)
 
for line in file:  # Read line by line
   if any(field in line for field in field_list):
       key, value = line.split(delimiter)
       d.append({key: value}) # Put the key value pair into d[count]
 
print(d)
```

Comment: Code looks good to me. Did you have a question in particular?

Comment: it doesn't work for large data that is very unique.

Comment: Ah, OK. Are you getting an error message, or are you determining that it doesn't work some other way?

Comment: I'm just lost on where to begin with my attempt. The code I used that work does not work for data that are no unique...